# How to make UIPickerView resignFirstResponder if user clicks in other place then UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I have created UIPickerView as following . Now i want to make it resignFirstResponder if user clicks in other place then UIPickerView How could i achieve that. I have created the UIPickerView as following way.Where else could I handle

`[pickerView removeFromSuperview];`

```
-(void)pickerview:(id)sender
{
    _items =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hindi",@"English",@"In what city were you born?",
             @"What was your childhood nickname?",
             @"Type your own question.",nil];

    pickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,350,300,300)];

    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
  //  [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [contentView addSubview:pickerView];


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

    return [_items count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return[_items objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [Txt_SecurityQue setText:[_items objectAtIndex:row]];
     NSLog(@"Did select");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer          
     alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Tap)];
    [contentView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)Tap {

   //write the UIPickerView resignFirstResponder code......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply add :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; 
        // write resignFirstResponder code......
}
```

Comment: Sorry dude its not working . Any way thanks for your suggestion

Comment: from where else do i have to call this function

Comment: its delegate method of UIResponder, so you don't need to call this.It calls when you touch on screen. and check your view if userInteractionEnabled is enable or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

Override the touchesBegan method, that is called when the user taps the view outside the pickerView. Then you can just simply call hide the pickerview.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:   UIEvent?) {
    pickerView.isHidden = true
}
```

Further reading on how to use touchesBegan:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
- (IBAction)btnCancel_Click:(id)sender
{
    [self.mypcikerview setHidden:YES];

}

- (IBAction)btnSelect_Click:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    labelQuestion.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array_from objectAtIndex:row]];
    [self.mypcikerview setHidden:YES];

}

where mypickerview is UIView with Pickerview , Select and cancel button
```